How to make a trendline in pandas and matplotlib from several different samples?
I have a set of data measuring oxygen consuption of several participants in a study. I have masured their oxygen consumption while lying in cold environments, wrapped in different layers of insulation material (Hypothermia study) Each participant (n=6) have tested 5 different insulation materials.
Now I want to make a trendline for the different insulation material used, combined for all six participans. I am using pandas, matplotlib and seaborn.
In the following code, I have tried to explain what I mean. I know i cannot use the bolean expression "and", but it is just to explain my point.
"vo2_01_m0" means oxygenconsuption(vo2) on participant 1 during metode 0, and so on.
So I want a trendline for all participants using methode 0 in this particular case.
I have already plotted a scatterplot with all the indivudual data.
Can anyone help me with this?
sns.regplot (x = "time", 
            y = "vo2_01_m0" and "vo2_02_m0"and "vo2_03_m0" and "vo2_04_m0" and "vo2_05_m0" and "vo2_06_m0", 
            data = df,
            order=6,
            color = "#e41a1c")

I am expecting a trendline for methode 0 in this particular example. Then I will further do the same with several methods of insulation.
